# Can't save trained Neural Network using keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, h5py

I cannot save the neural network I trained in h5py format. It shows the following error :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-0185b568b480> in <module>()
      1 from keras.models import load_model
----> 2 model.save("MNISTclassifier.h5")

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   2470         """
   2471         from ..models import save_model
-> 2472         save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   2473 
   2474     def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
     53 
     54     if h5py is None:
---> 55         raise ImportError('`save_model` requires h5py.')
     56 
     57     def get_json_type(obj):

ImportError: `save_model` requires h5py.
```

Even though I have installed h5py using pip and imported it.
Source code here :
https://github.com/tanmay-edgelord/HandwrittenDigitRecognition/blob/master/MNIST%20.ipynb

Comment: Will the fixes suggested [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3426) solve your problem?

Comment: rebooting the PC solved my problem. I didnt even change my code. Like I didnt even add a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `model.save(filepath)` to save a Keras model into a single HDF5 file which will contain:

1. the architecture of the model, allowing to re-create the model
2. the weights of the model
3. the training configuration (loss, optimizer)
4. the state of the optimizer, allowing to resume training exactly where you left off.

You can then use `keras.models.load_model(filepath)` to reinstantiate your model. `load_model` will also take care of compiling the model using the saved training configuration (unless the model was never compiled in the first place).

Example:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
```